# how can I transfer large data over tcp socket

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, data-transfer, large-data

how can I transfer large data without splitting. Am using tcp socket. Its for a game. I cant use udp and there might be 1200 values in an array. Am sending array in json format. But the server receiving it like splitted.

Also is there any option to send http request like tcp? I need the response in order. Also it should be faster.

Thanks,

Comment: The smaller the packet the better the chance of it not being split, but you can't ever control whether splitting happens unless you own the network end to end.

Comment: Don't use JSON. If all of those 1,200 values are at most one byte, you can use a binary array with fixed variable positions. That will almost certainly be smaller than your current MTU. And if you need to receive everything in order, considder a long-living connection instead of many small ones.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

- HTTP may chunk it
- TCP will segment it
- IP will packetize it
- routers will fragment it ...
- and TCP will reassemble it all at the other end.

There isn't a problem here to solve.

Comment: Its a game connection with 1200 values. Its a turn based game. Its communicating with server. Can you suggest a best option for this?

Comment: A best option for what? You'll have to ask a proper question if you want an answer. How big for example is a 'value'? One byte? One gigabyte?

Comment: "HTTP may chunk it" - can you point out where in the spec that is?  "There isn't a problem here to solve."  The problem to solve is latency.

Comment: @xaxxon (a) [RFC 2616 # 3.6.1 Chunked Transfer Encoding](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). (b) There is no evidence that latency is any kind of a problem for the OP, or that preventing fragmentation will solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have much control over splitting packets/datagrams. The network decides about this. 
In the case of IP, you have the DF (don't fragment) flag, but I doubt it will be of much help here. If you are communicating over Ethernet, then 1200 element array may not fit into an Ethernet frame (payload size is up to the MTU of 1500 octets).
Why does your application depend on the fact that the whole data must arrive in a single unit, and not in a single connection (comprised potentially of multiple units)?

Comment: Its a game connection with 1200 values. Its a turn based game. Its communicating with server. Is there any other option I could use? Tried http request and its slow . Also I need messages in order, thats not the case when am using http.

Comment: So what is your **real** problem? Even 1200*1200 values is not an issue in network communication. Why do you not like splitting and so much want to relay on **single** datagrams/packets? Why does not your server wait for the whole connection (=packet/datagram sequence) to finish before processing this data?

Comment: when sending that much data, it is taking some time. It is splitting the data to 4 . So its taking around 5-6 seconds in slow network connection. I sould reduce the time. Only 5 seconds is given to change the turn from one player to another.

Comment: I do not know what you mean with 'slow http' - I supose you are testing it in a small environment. Check your HTTP server configuration/performance. It is true that stacking any other protocols/formats on top of your data creates overhead. But his overhead is probably negligible with the current slight (I suppose) load. But if the connection is not fast enough right now - how will it be in a real environment?

Comment: @user2393848: I do not not how much octets are in your 1200 elements transferred over 5 seconds. But anyway the time it takes depends on network bandwidth and latency. If you think that fragmented transmission is the culprit, that means that **you think that latency is the cause**, not bandwidth. So a new question: why does your network have such a long latency? If such long latency is unavoidable for you - you have to compress/reduce your data or change your initial assumptions/goals regarding 5 second steps...

Comment: The game might be using in slow internet by any users in world. So I cant predict their internet speed. If the splitting is avoided , I think the handshake time will reduce and I could reduce the latency to 1/4 . If its not possible, can anyone suggest a best option to transfer such data to server.

Comment: You have no handshake if using UDP. Framgentation does not require handshaking, btw. If you really see handshakes, then you send data in four **TCP connections** not in four **TCP packets** - and that can mean that your are out of control in the communication part. As for the other options to solve see my previous comment.

Comment: user2393848: How is your progress on this? It might be wort to reformulate your question or re-post another one, since the topic shifted way from the starting point

Answer (score 1):

Consider the idea that the issue may be else where or that you may be sending too much unnecessary data. In example with PHP there is the `isset()` function. If you're creating an internet based turn based game you don't (*need* to send all 1,200 variables back and forth every single time. Just send what changed and when the other player receives that data only change the variables are are *set*.

Comment: Actually its a turn based game with 1200 betting values. So it should be saved in database.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I transfer large data without splitting.

I'm interpreting the above to be roughly equivalent to "how can I transfer my data across a TCP connection using as few TCP packets as possible".  As others have noted, there is no way to *guarantee* that your data will be placed into a single TCP packet -- but you can do some things to make it more likely.  Here are some things I would do:

1. Keep a single TCP connection open.  (HTTP traditionally opens a separate TCP connection for each request, but for low-latency you can't afford to do that.  Instead you need to open a single TCP connection, keep it open, and continue sending/receiving data on it for as long as necessary).
2. Reduce the amount of data you need to send.  (i.e. are there things that you are sending that the receiving program already knows?  If so, don't send them)
3. Reduce the number of bytes you need to send.  (The easiest way to do this is to [zlib](http://zlib.net)-compress your message-data before you send it, and have the receiving program decompress the message after receiving it.  This can give you a size-reduction of 50-90%, depending on the content of your data)
4. Turn off [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) on your TCP socket.  That will reduce latency by 200mS and discourage the TCP stack from playing unnecessary games with your data.
5. Send each data packet with a single send() call (if that means manually copying all of the data items into a separate memory buffer before calling send(), then so be it).

Note that even after you do all of the above, the TCP layer will still sometimes spread your messages across multiple packets, etc -- that's just the way TCP works.  And even if your local TCP stack never did that, the receiving computer's TCP stack would still sometimes merge the data from consecutive TCP packets together inside its receive buffer.  So the receiving program is always going to "receive it like splitted" sometimes, because TCP is a stream-based protocol and does not maintain message boundaries.  (If you want message boundaries, you'll have to do your own framing -- the easiest way is usually to send a fixed-size (e.g. 1, 2, or 4-byte) integer byte-count field before each message, so the receiver knows how many bytes it needs to read in before it has a full message to parse)

Comment: You are 17 years out of date. HTTP 1.1 'traditionally' uses `Connection: keepalive`.